# How to get tkinter canvas to dynamically resize to window ,staying centered ,in python3

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, resizable

I would like to create a visual display, which is constisted of differents canvas that I call at differents instant in my main script. Moreover they have all a specific duration. I would like the canvas centered in my window and my window resizable. Moreover, I would like to display this window over a second screen connected to my computer. 
So far, I succeed in creating the windows and canvas. I reused the class ResizingCanvas(Canvas) sudmitted by ebarr on an other post  in stackoverflow. But : canvas and windows are not centered; when I maximize the window :the canvas won't follow ; when I want to close the window : the close button is not working. In cross, I tried to create a white cross in the middle of the canvas.
If you have,also, any idea on how to display my window on another screen it would be awesome. Thanks in advance for your time and answer!

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import font
import time


class ResizingCanvas(tkinter.Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        tkinter.Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()

    def on_resize(self,event):
        # determine the ratio of old width/height to new width/height
        wscale = float(event.width)/self.width
        hscale = float(event.height)/self.height
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        # resize the canvas 
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        # rescale all the objects tagged with the "all" tag
        self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)

class display():
    def __init__(self, Reponse=None,):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk() # Création de la fenêtre racine
        self.root.title('Feedback') # Ajout d'un titre
        self.myframe = tkinter.Frame(self.root)
        self.myframe.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=tkinter.YES)
        self.mycanvas = ResizingCanvas(self.myframe,width=850, height=400, bg="black", highlightthickness=0)

        # tag all of the drawn widgets
        self.mycanvas.addtag_all("all")

        self.helv36 = font.Font(self.root,family="Helvetica",size=24, weight="bold")
        font.families()

    def test(self):        
        self.mycanvas.create_text(100,100,text=" Bonne réponse ", fill="white")
        self.mycanvas.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=tkinter.YES)
        self.root.update()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.clear()

    def returnReponse(self,Reponse): 
        if(Reponse==True):
            self.mycanvas.create_text(300, 300, text=" Bonne réponse ", fill="white",font=self.helv36)
        else:         
            self.mycanvas.create_text(300, 300, text=" Mauvaise réponse ", fill="white",font=self.helv36)
        self.mycanvas.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=tkinter.YES)
        self.root.update()
        time.sleep(1.250)
        self.clear()

    def cross(self):
        self.mycanvas.create_rectangle((-150,-50),(150,50), fill='white',outline ='white', width=2)
        self.mycanvas.create_rectangle((50,150),(50,150), fill='white',outline='white', width=2)
        self.mycanvas.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=tkinter.YES)
        self.root.update()
        time.sleep(0.250)
        self.clear()

    def clear(self):
        self.canvas.delete('all')
        self.root.update() 



fenetre=display()

fenetre.test()
fenetre.cross()
fenetre.returnReponse(True)
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken.

Comment: Even with the good indentation, it is not working. Using Thread can be a solution ?

Comment: No, threads will not help at all. We can't help you if we can't reproduce your problem. If you expect free help, you've got to put in a little effort.